# How to decode base64 string before downloading images in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of encoded string for images download and fetch data from API, I want the user to be able to click the download button to have the images locally.

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {

//example of API data
//  const URLs = ["data:image/jpg;base64,b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAY..."]

  const handleDownload = async () => {
        

         Axios({
            url: `${baseUrl}/bulk/images/download`,
            method: "GET",
            responseType: "blob",
         })
            .then((response) => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute("download", "file.jpg");
            document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Download Images</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleDownload}>
        download
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

From the API is 500 list of encoded strings to download. This implementation is what I got on search but it doesn't work as it throws exceptions. Please what's the most clean way to implement this on how to down images in bulk and in a sequence?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Your code is missing the `import Axios from 'axios'`. After adding, your code works fine for me.